# Copy RichTextBox string based on string position

Tags: vb.net

I have a long TXT string imported into a RichTextBox. I am trying to copy a portion of that text using beginning and end points based on text strings. Here is what I have so far,

```
    Dim StartsearchString As String = "MyStartString"
    Dim EndSearchString As String = "MyEndString"
    Dim Length As Integer
    Dim StartPoint As Integer
    Dim EndPoint As Integer
    Length1 = Len(StartsearchString)
    Length2 = Len(EndSearchString)
    StartPoint = Form2.RichTextBox2.Find(StartsearchString) + Length1
    EndPoint = Form2.RichTextBox2.Find(EndSearchString) - Length2
```

How can I copy the text between the Start and End points and paste it into a new RichTextBox?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your EndPoint is off since you don't have to substract the length of the EndString.  That is, the Find method is finding the beginning of that index.

I re-worked it this way using the SubString function:

```
Dim StartsearchString As String = "MyStartString"
Dim EndSearchString As String = "MyEndString"
Dim StartPoint As Integer = RichTextBox2.Find(StartsearchString)
Dim EndPoint As Integer = RichTextBox2.Find(EndSearchString)
If EndPoint > StartPoint Then
  OtherRTB.Text = RichTextBox2.Text.Substring(
                     StartPoint + StartsearchString.Length,
                     EndPoint - StartPoint - StartsearchString.Length)
End If
```